# Integer error in code

Tags: python, string, integer

I am trying to write some code that will calculate the speed of cars with different number plates, correct format and incorrect. The program will print speeding cars with incorrect format in a separate text file. This is the error I just got and I have no idea on how to solve it:

```
import re
distance = 200
speedlimit = 50
nonstandardReg = open("text.txt ","w")

userinput = input("Choose a car number 1 to 5")
if userinput ==('1')or(' 1')or('car1')or(' car1'):
 car1 = "AD 12DER, 12:36:01, 12:36:40"
elif userinput ==('2')or(' 2')or('car2')or(' car2'):
 car2 = "DE 61FE1, 02:47:01, 02:47:30"
elif userinput == ('3')or(' 3')or('car3')or(' car3'):
 car3 = "AF 012GL, 04:08:32, 07:32:28"
elif userinput == ('4')or(' 4')or('car4')or(' car4'):
 car4 = "TG 043WE, 08:45:23, 12:14:56"
elif userinput == ('5')or(' 5')or('car5')or(' car5'):
 car5 = "TL 12AWY"
else:
 print("Invalid Car")
car1Time1 =int(car1[16:18])
car1Time2 =int(car1[26:28])
car1TimeEnd = car1Time2-car1Time1
car1Speed = distance/car1TimeEnd

car2Time1 =int(car2[16:18])
car2Time2 =int(car2[26:28])
car2TimeEnd = car2Time2-car2Time1
car2Speed = distance/car2TimeEnd

car3Time1 =int(car3[16:18])
car3Time2 =int(car3[26:28])
car3TimeEnd = car3Time2-car3Time1
car3Speed = distance/car3TimeEnd

car4Time1 =int(car4[16:18])
car4Time2 =int(car4[26:28])
car4TimeEnd = car4Time2-car4Time1
car4Speed = distance/car4TimeEnd

car5Time1 =int(car5[16:18])
car5Time2 =int(car5[26:28])
car5TimeEnd = car5Time2-car5Time1
car5Speed = distance/car5TimeEnd
```

This is the error I get:

```
car2Time1 =(int(car2[16:18]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Why don't you use a loop? You are repeating too many things.

Comment: Does it only do it for car 2 or all cars?

Comment: if user input is 1, then car2 through car5 won't exist. I would expect a 'car2 not defined' error.

Comment: it only calculates the speed for one car and then it has the error on the rest

Comment: @Ryan what could I do to actually make them exist?

Comment: @ Ahsanul Haque im not this good at coding :/

Comment: What are you doing with the user input? It looks like you want data for all 5 cars regardless of what the user inputs.

Comment: Also you will have an error when you do car5[16:18] because you made car5 a short string.

Comment: @ryan but what could I do?thats what I mean

Comment: should I after they check 1 car ask them if they want to check another one and so on to car5?

Comment: @Ryan you should go ahead and make an answer :) seems like you know the problem

Comment: @Kuboos Do you want it to print only the car the user chooses?

Comment: @DeliriousSyntax yes but I want to print it in a text file if the number plate is in the incorrect format

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it sounds like you're not sure what you want the program to do. It's possible you're looking for something like this:

```
if userinput ==('1')or userinput ==(' 1')or userinput ==('car1')or userinput ==(' car1'):
 car = "AD 12DER, 12:36:01, 12:36:40"
elif userinput ==('2')or userinput ==(' 2')or userinput ==('car2')or userinput ==(' car2'):
 car = "DE 61FE1, 02:47:01, 02:47:30"
elif userinput == ('3')or userinput ==(' 3')or userinput ==('car3')or userinput ==(' car3'):
 car = "AF 012GL, 04:08:32, 07:32:28"
elif userinput == ('4')or userinput ==(' 4')or userinput ==('car4')or userinput ==(' car4'):
 car = "TG 043WE, 08:45:23, 12:14:56"
elif userinput == ('5')or userinput ==(' 5')or userinput ==('car5')or userinput ==(' car5'):
 car = "TL 12AWY"
else:
 print("Invalid Car")
carTime1 =int(car[16:18])
carTime2 =int(car[26:28])
carTimeEnd = carTime2-carTime1
carSpeed = distance/carTimeEnd
```

Now, if they try to use car5, you'll have a problem because you shortened that one to not include timing information.

Comment: @Kuboos What's your plan for fixing the problem with the 5th car??

Comment: I will give it a time at which it passed the first sensor and then a time at which it passed the last sensor

Comment: i have a question, how would i get a non standard number plate printed in a separate txt file that it was speeding?

Comment: There are many questions with good examples of printing to a file in Python. I would start there. Then try your own, and if it doesn't work, ask another question. :)

Comment: if re.match ("[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]:
             print " "

Comment: ryan that gives me an EOL while scanning

Comment: @Ryan im trying to get to code to figure out if the cars number plate is correct to the format and if it is the code should print nothing and if it isn't in correct format i want it to print that the car was speeding in a separate text file called nonstandardreg.Can you help again please?

Comment: I don't know what a valid plate is.

Comment: the valid plate is letter,letter,number,number,letter,letter,letter UK format

Comment: if re.match([A-Z][A-Z]\s[0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z], plate): print "" where plate is a substring of car that contains only the plate.

Comment: @Ryan could you make a bit where if the plate is not in the correct format it will print it in a separate text file please?

Answer (score 0):

Your code have several issues. At first, this condition

```
if userinput ==('1')or(' 1')or('car1')or(' car1'):
```

will be always evaluated to `True`. You should use

```
if userinput ==('1') or userinput==(' 1') or userinput==('car1') or userinput == (' car1'):
```

instead. And so on with `elif` statements. Then you need only one `car` variable:

```
if userinput ==('1') or userinput==(' 1') or userinput==('car1') or userinput == (' car1'):
 car = "AD 12DER, 12:36:01, 12:36:40"
...
elif userinput ==('5') or userinput==(' 5') or userinput==('car5') or userinput == (' car5'):
 car = "TL 12AWY"
else:
 print("Invalid Car")
carTime1 =int(car[16:18])
carTime2 =int(car[26:28])
carTimeEnd = carTime2-carTime1
carSpeed = distance/carTimeEnd
```

And you need properly init `car` variable for car5.

Comment: if re.match ("[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]"):
TypeError: match() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string' could you help me with this problem, im trying to get the code to know if the car reg is in correct format and if it is i want it to print nothing and if it is in incorrect format i want the code to print that the car was speeding + its reg in a separate text file called nonstandard reg

Comment: @Kuboos `re.match` [requires](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) two arguments - pattern and string. And you trying it with only pattern arg.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite sure if this code is helpful to you, but you should redesign your code, unless it is very hard to find bugs.

```
car_dict={

'car1': "AD 12DER, 12:36:01, 12:36:40",
'car2': "DE 61FE1, 02:47:01, 02:47:30",
'car3': "AF 012GL, 04:08:32, 07:32:28",
'car4': "TG 043WE, 08:45:23, 12:14:56",
'car5': "TL 12AWY"
}

def speed_calculator(st, distance =200):
    start_time= int(st[16:18])
    end_time= int(st[26:28])
    time_in_between = end_time - start_time
    return distance/time_in_between

userinput = raw_input("Choose a car number 1 to 5").strip()


for key in car_dict:
    if userinput in key:
        print speed_calculator(car_dict[key])
```

Comment: could you also add a bit where it prints nothing if the number plate is in the format letter letter number number letter letter letter and if it isn't to print the car + its reg and say it was speeding in a separate text file called non standard reg

Comment: your code has a syntax error on the speed calculator

Comment: Runs successfully on my machine, probably you are using python3.x and error is due to `raw_input`.

Comment: what would i need to change then?

Comment: may  use `userinput = str(input("Choose a car number 1 to 5")).strip()` in place of current input statement.

Comment: @ Ahsanul Haque that has still not fixed the invalid syntax on the print speed_calculator..

Comment: Use `print( speed_calculator(car_dict[key]))` in place of `print speed_calculator(car_dict[key])`

Comment: could you make a bit where it sets the car number plate to [0:8] and also if the re does not match A-Z][A-Z]\s[0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z] the car number plate needs to be printed in a text file